# Is it possible to convert binary to decimal by just using loops

Tags: java

Hi guys i just wanted to know if it's possible to convert Binary numbers into Decimal numbers by just using loops and no other advance codes. The codes below are just a program that converts Decimal numbers into Binary but i want the to make one that convert Binary into Decimal just by using loops.

```
  System.out.print("Enter Decimal: ");
    int decimal = pal.nextInt();

    int num = 1;
    int binary = 0;
    for(int j=decimal;j>0;j/=2)
    {
        binary = binary +(decimal%2)*num;
        num = num * 10;
        decimal = decimal / 2;
    }

    System.out.println("The binary is: "+binary);
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-binary-decimal-conversion/

Comment: You can just use: Integer.toBinaryString(); this is not "advance codes", it's part of the basic classes

Comment: Actually, your program does something, that is not really useful. For example it converts the number 3 to the number 11 (eleven). That's not really binary.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in function : `Integer.toBinaryString()`

Answer (score 0):

Note:

You can generalize this code for decimal representations as well.

Also you can take in the input from the user,since you only need the basic idea hence i have omitted these things.

Also since no particular language is preferred, i have chosen python.

You can go by simple for loops:

```
b="111"    #LET US ASSUME THE BINARY NUMBER IS "111"
bb=list(b)
for i in range(0,len(bb)):
    bb[i]=int(bb[i])
d=0
for i in range(0,len(bb)):
    d=d+(bb[i])*(2)**(i)
print(d)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will do.Here is what i did ,take a binary String as input split it on `"."` because we are dealing with fractional also. Go to first splitted part(ie. Integer part) calculate integer value form it. Go to second part(fractional part) if there are any calculate the fractional value and then add both.

```
 private static void printDecimal(String binaryString) {
        float result = 0;
        String[] StringArr = binaryString.split("\\.");
        if (StringArr.length > 2) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Binary Number");
        } else {
            String IntegerPart = StringArr[0];
            int c = 0;
            for (int i = IntegerPart.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                result += Integer.valueOf("" + IntegerPart.charAt(i)) * Math.pow(2, c);
                c++;
            }
            if (StringArr.length == 2) {
                String fractionPart = StringArr[1];
                for (int i = 0; i < fractionPart.length(); i++) {
                    result += Integer.valueOf("" + fractionPart.charAt(i)) * Math.pow(2, -1 * (i + 1));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```